# How does SQL logic in this php 'know' what to select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I apologise if the title is poor.

I have been researching Prepared Statements and found the following code [here](http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/):

```
  /* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      exit();
   }

   /* Create a prepared statement */
   if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT priv FROM testUsers WHERE username=?
   AND password=?")) {
  /* Bind parameters
     s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
  $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);

  /* Execute it */
  $stmt -> execute();

  /* Bind results */
  $stmt -> bind_result($result);

  /* Fetch the value */
  $stmt -> fetch();

  echo $user . "'s level of priviledges is " . $result;

  /* Close statement */
  $stmt -> close();
  }

  /* Close connection */
  $mysqli -> close();
```

The part that I don't understand, is how in the SQL Query `"SELECT priv FROM testUsers WHERE username=?
   AND password=?")`, the system knows what the username and password is. I know that the ? marks are placeholders, and below is also confusing me a bit:

```
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
```

Because I do not see how the `$user` and `$pass` have been defined at any point, and thus how the SQL query will substitute the `$user` and `$pass` for an actual string. If that makes sense. Where have these values come from? Where are they in this example?

Comment: There must be some additional code that assigns value to `$user` and `$pass`. The article assumes they are initialized elsewhere.

Comment: You have to get $user and $pass from the form from where they are posted. May be in the script you posted that has been missed out.

Comment: You don't understand prepared statements, or you don't understand where `$user` and `$pass` are coming from? They have to come from somewhere, this has nothing to do with any SQL magic.

Comment: +1 for researching prepared statements :-)

Comment: @deceze both. But I am getting better at understanding them at least. I saw this example and was just very confused because the writer gives no indication as to where $user and $pass has come from. I don't mean to bash the writer of course because he says at the top that this article is for those that already know PHP and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because they aren't. This is probably just an example how to use the script. You will have to define the $user and $pass variables by yourself, for example from an $_POST variable of some sort.

The bind_param function handles the arguments. You have to add the same amount of arguments to the query as you put question marks in it. Than the parser in the core of MySQLi can add the arguments safely to the query.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm glad that my assumption was, in part, correct in that the code presented doesn't just work standalone, because I was mighty confused otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

They are being matched by order. Same logic in string building ("{0} is greater than {1}", "5", "3") becomes *5 is greater than 3*. So with parameters

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

they are all ordered and matches with columns.

Answer (score 0):

If the original script writer had register_globals ON, e.g. in a previous version of PHP, then the user and pass were passed in from the form in the same way as $_POST['user'] and $_POST['pass']. I offer that you can replace them now and move on.